# Compare two lists and return values not contained in the other list

Tags: mysql

```
Employee List (List 1)

USER ID    NAME
1          John 
2          Jane 
3          Rob
4          Bill
5          Sally

Enrolled Students (List 1)

ID   PID     USER_ID
1     1        1
2     1        2
3     2        1
4     2        2
5     2        3
```

I am trying to find a way to determine if I want to look up who is not enrolled in x course.

So if I wanted to know which employees were not enrolled in Course 1 the result would be

```
USER_ID
3
4
5
```

Then if I wanted to know who is not enrolled in course 2

```
USER_ID
4
5
```

I tried this however it returns all students enrolled in the course. Where if the student has not been enrolled there is no NULL pid.

```
SELECT e.user_id, e.full_name, es.student
FROM employees e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     enrolled_students es 
     ON e.user_id = es.student AND es.pid = 40
WHERE e.level = 3 AND es.student IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: There are columns in the query that don’t appear in the data model, but apart from that, looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

First we have to check who does enrolled in the course, then we have to get the list of names containing the other names except the ones returned in the first part of the query. Something like this can be done for this purpose:

```
SELECT 
    e1.*
FROM
    employee e1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        e.user_id
    FROM
        employee e
    JOIN enrolled_student es ON e.user_id = es.user_id
    WHERE
        es.pid = 1) t ON e1.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE
    t.user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id from users where id not in (select user_id from enrolled where pid = 1)
```

Selects all users, which are not enrolled to course 1.